# In Autofac, is it possible to register a generic type for a non-generic interface?

Tags: generics, autofac

I'm trying to register a generic class as follows:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(WindowContext<>))
    .AsSelf()
    .As<IWindowContext>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

(`WindowContext<T> : IWindowContext`)

The above registration causes an `ArgumentException` on build: *The service 'Inforbase.Presentation.IWindowContext' is not an open generic type definition.*

The expected behavior is that the dependency on a `WindowContext<T>` closest to the composition root, will define the instance resolved for any `IWindowContext` within that lifetime scope.

I realize the concept is a bit strange, and has a curious edge case where two classes within the same lifetime scope request different types of `WindowContext<T>`. Both an error or an overwrite are acceptable in my scenario.

Is this possible with Autofac?

Comment: I would still like to know why this is not possible, the open-generic might be used as a non-generic dependency in another class instance and not just the composition root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that what I'm asking doesn't really make sense. The objects furthest away from the composition root in the dependency graph are the ones that need to be created first, and they wouldn't be able to resolve `IWindowContext`, because at the time when they're resolved, the concrete type of `IWindowContext` wouldn't have been defined yet.

The best way out is probably to reorganize the class structure, by making WindowContext non-generic. Luckily this is just an experiment, and not something I actually require in my architecture.